# "VC method not implemented for backend" for project-find call

Tags: search, project, etags

I am trying out project based search via `project-find-regexp`, but I get the error:

```
vc-call-backend: VC method not implemented for backend: find-ignore-file, CVS
```

How can I fix this? I assume this is a CVS specific problem. Is there way to make CVS working with the project system? (Or just ignoring the CVS aspect when doing the project search?)

Comment: Apparently `project` (and thus `vc`) think your project is using CVS as its version control. Check the docs for each to see how to explicitly set the version control system for your project. Or you can customize `vc-enabled-backends`, to set which backends `vc` will use. If you're just interested in searching, maybe Emacs integration for one of the "fast search tools" (ack, ag, ripgrep, etc.) would be more suited to your needs.

Comment: @nega Thx for chiming in. The project *is* using CVS! I thought Emacs supports CVS.

Comment: oh my! ;) Emacs does support CVS with `vc`, but not for ignoring files apparently. In my copy of `vc` the backend specific functions are only implemented for git, bzr, hg, and mtn. This might be helpful though https://github.com/wolfmanx/vc-ign

Comment: Does CVS have anything similar to `svn propget svn:ignore`?

Comment: Yes, it does. You can create a file called `cvsignore` where you list the file patterns that you want CVS to ignore. See the documentation online (https://www.gnu.org/software/trans-coord/manual/cvs/html_node/cvsignore.html).

Comment: @db48x I mean, like a command to fetch all applicable ignore entries. The drawback in doing it the way I proposed is that there can be many `.cvsignore` files (inside the repo and in the user's home directory), as well as `CVSROOT/cvsignore`. The code would need to check them all.

Comment: Oh, I misread your question :)

Comment: No, I don’t think that it does. I’m not sure that needing to check all of the files is really relevant; that is also true for git but `vc-git-find-ignore-file` exists. Personally, I think the correct answer is to replace `find` with `rg`. `rg` already correctly handles all types of ignore files, even recursively. There’s no need to attempt to specify the same information on the command line.

Comment: `find` is replaced with `git ls-files` in the usual case (though not with CVS, of course). `rg` is a fine option, but it's not installed everywhere, and it needs integration code to support user-specified additional ignore entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick workaround, you can try adding this definition to your init script:

```lisp
(defun vc-cvs-find-ignore-file (file)
  (expand-file-name ".cvsignore" (file-name-directory file)))
```

Comment: Thx. Looks promising. Will try it out next week.

Comment: It’s an odd oversight for the vc package to be missing this function; someone should file a bug.

Comment: Seems like not too many people care about CVS these days. But a report will be good to have indeed.

Comment: The function works like a charm. Will file a bug report to the `bug-gnu-emacs` list.